# Why didn't git push ignore .gitignore?

Tags: git, github, cmd

I will walk you picture by picture through all the steps which I took before running into my problem :

1. I created new repository EXACTLY like in the picture below.
   [image]
2. In the picture below you can see the folder in which are included the files and folders I want to be pushed; these are : "1day" folder and "README.txt" file. I do not want to push "Resources" directory.

[image]

3. I enter the folder in the picture above and open a Git Bash, then i run "git intit" for initializing git repository.
4. I created the file .gitignore like in the picture below (I created new text file, but remove the extension and add a "." after, like this : ".gitignore.txt --> ".gitignore."

[image]

5. So here I wrote in the ".gitignore" file this :

*1st time : "Resources" (after running step "6)" Resources directory had been pushed, so i deleted the repository and tried again)*

*2nd time : "Resources\" (after running step "6)" Resources directory had been pushed, so i deleted the repository and tried again)*

*3rd time : "Resources.dir" (Resources directory had been pushed)*

6. I run the next 3 lines :

git remote add origin https://github.com/perjoraxul/100-Days-of-Code-The-Complete-Python-Pro-Bootcamp-for-2022.git

git branch -M main

git push -u origin main

What do i do the ignore Resources directory?

Comment: This is because you added the resources/ file before creating the .gitignore. Remove the Resources/ file from your commit history. To do that see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602985/4967403

Comment: `git push` sends *commits*, not files. Commits contain whatever files they contain: a `.gitignore` file does not change the set of files that an existing commit contains. Once made, a commit is completely unchangeable.

Comment: If you have a commit you don't like (and/or can't push), you need to just stop using that commit entirely. If it's the very last commit on a branch, this is easy; if it's embedded further back, this is harder to do.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for the answer. I will consider this as an apropriate answer for my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
Resources/
```

in the .gitignore file

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, but it didn't work.